# centering google maps overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to make an overlay that looks like a target. That 'target' overlay should be always centered and not clickable and should behave like a map tile.
When i append it to a map tile as a ground overlay the 'target' moves with the scope.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay

I also thought i could use http://mabp.kiev.ua/2010/09/10/raphael-overlay/ (ground overlays with raphael js in russian..)

How can i create a native maps overlay that is not attached to a map tile?

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855718/specific-way-of-selecting-a-location-on-a-google-map/9855808#9855808. "Another suggestion" may be interesting to you.

Comment: i already tried to implement it as a custom control but that solution did not suit my needs. I think canvas and a ground overlay is the way to go.

Comment: did you find a solution? I want to achive the same result.. a fixed target, even when moving the map.

Answer (score 0):

On the example [Custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) I used the following code to center it (`CENTER` instead of `TOP_CENTER`)

```
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
```

This works fine for me.